# Teams Graph API Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to use Graph API using teams presences. When I try to subscribe then I get this error. I registered add with required permissions:

`"subscribe123: {\"error\":{\"code\":\"ExtensionError\",\"message\":\"Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application.]\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2023-04-26T14:14:12\",\"request-id\":\"02a4fbh4-2947-414c-9ac6-3bb6738acc9908c\",\"client-request-id\":\"02a3fbb4-2947-4614c-9ac6-3bb38ac90908cc\"}}}"`

I also added client secret and having Application (client) ID, Directory (tenant) ID, Object ID,

```
        $guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions';

        $response = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '$bearer,
            ],
            'json' => [
            // 'form_params' => [
                'changeType' => 'created',
                'notificationUrl' => 'https://api-myapi.com/teams/notification',
                'resource' => '/communications/presences/'.$row['teams_user_id'],
                //'expirationDateTime' => '2023-04-21T08:00:00.0000000Z',
                 'expirationDateTime' => $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.0000000\Z'),
                'clientState' => 'secretClientValue',
                "latestSupportedTlsVersion" => "v1_2",
            ],
        ])->getBody()->getContents());
```